# Problems getting my PHP form to successfully query database to check and see if email already exists

Tags: php, mysql, sql

For some reason my form is not checking the database to see if the email already exists. Are you able to identify anything wrong with my code?

```
// If the form submit button is set and the email and zip fields are not empty, proceed and process 
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['zip'])) {  

    // Create variables for form input fields
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $zip = $_POST['zip'];

    // Create an array to capture errors
    $errors = array();

    // Create variable to capture success message
    $success = "Thanks for signing up!";

    // Email Validation
    // Check to see if user entered a valid email
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errors[] = "Invalid email address.";
    }
    // Check email length
    if (strlen($email) < 6) {
        $errors[] = "Sorry your email is too short.";
    }
    // Check email length
    if (strlen($email) > 50) {
        $errors[] = "Sorry your email is too long.";
    }

    // Zip Code Validation
    // Check to see if zip code is a number
    if (!is_numeric($zip)) {
        $errors[] = "Zip code must be a number.";
    }
    // Check to see if zip code equals 5 characters
    if (strlen($zip) != 5) {
        $errors[] = "Sorry not a valid zip code.";
    }

    // Include database config file and establish db connection
    require("includes/config.php");
    $connection = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Database Connection Error");
    $database = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME) or die("No Database Found");

    // Check to see if email already exists in database
    $email_check_query = "SELECT email FROM shotgun";
    $run_email_check_query = mysql_query($email_check_query);

    // If MySQL query returns any results, user has already signed up
    if (mysql_fetch_assoc($run_email_check_query) == $email) {
        $errors[] = "Looks like you already signed up...";
    }

    // If there are no errors above run this block of code
    if (count($errors) == 0) {

        // Include database config file and establish db connection
        require("includes/config.php");
        $connection = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Database Connection Error");
        $database = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME) or die("No Database Found");

        // Insert email and password into database
        $insert_email_query = "INSERT INTO shotgun (email,zip) VALUES ('$email','$zip')";
        $run_insert_email_query = mysql_query($insert_email_query);
    }   
} 
?>
```

Site

```
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="logo">
            <h1>Site</h1>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="comingsoon"></div>
        <h1>Sign Up Now</h1>
        <p class="description">Description</p>
        <form action="index.php" method="post">
            <input type="email" class="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
            <input type="text" class="zip" name="zip" max="5" placeholder="Zip Code">
            <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            <span class="errors">
            <?php 
                if (count($errors) != 0) { 
                    foreach($errors as $error) { 
                        echo $error . "<br />";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo $success; 
                }
            ?>
            </span>
        </form>
    </div>
    <footer><a href="test.com" title="test"></a></footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$email_check_query = "SELECT email FROM datingshotgun";
```

should be

```
$email_check_query = "SELECT email FROM datingshotgun WHERE email='$email'";
```

Right now you allways query ALL emails and compare the new email to the first in the DB.

EDIT: After tracking your code, you need:

```
$dbemail=mysql_real_escape_string($email, $connection);
$email_check_query = "SELECT email FROM datingshotgun WHERE email='$dbemail'";
```

Comment: Also, after you do what Eugen Rieck said, you must check if the SELECT query returned 1 row or not. If it did, the user is already registered. You can do this: mysql_num_rows ($email_check_query) == 1.